# How to put results from fzero into a column matrix

Tags: matlab, math, optimization

I think I already solved this problem, but how do I upload the `x` values of each iteration from `fzero` into a column matrix? I've already found the zero using bisection and the results seem to match up.

[image]

When I run the code:

```
% second part
clear all; close all;
x= 100:0.01:200; % domain
f = @(x) sqrt((x*9.8)/0.25)* tanh(sqrt((0.25 * 9.8) / x) * 4) - 36;

%x02 = fzero(f, 100, optimset('Tolx', 1*e*(-6))) % What's the point
%of this?
x03 = fzero(f, 100, optimset('Display', 'iter')) % 100 is initial starting point
```

I get this:

```
Search for an interval around 100 containing a sign change:
 Func-count    a          f(a)             b          f(b)        Procedure
    1             100      -1.22895           100      -1.22895   initial interval
    3         97.1716      -1.34001       102.828      -1.12319   search
    5              96      -1.38767           104      -1.08085   search
    7         94.3431      -1.45679       105.657      -1.02236   search
    9              92      -1.55819           108     -0.942334   search
   11         88.6863      -1.70937       111.314     -0.834198   search
   13              84      -1.94034           116     -0.690568   search
   15         77.3726      -2.30675       122.627     -0.504071   search
   17              68      -2.92417           132     -0.268914   search
   19         54.7452      -4.07851       145.255     0.0168687   search

Search for a zero in the interval [54.7452, 145.255]:
 Func-count    x          f(x)             Procedure
   19         145.255     0.0168687        initial
   20         144.882    0.00947591        interpolation
   21         144.405  -2.82264e-05        interpolation
   22         144.407   8.38448e-08        interpolation
   23         144.407    7.4607e-13        interpolation
   24         144.407  -1.42109e-14        interpolation
   25         144.407             0        interpolation

Zero found in the interval [54.7452, 145.255]

x03 =

  144.4067
```

Which compares similarly to 144.4092 using bisection. In addition, I tried to set the tolerance to 10(-6), but I couldn't get it to work, what did I do wrong? Or am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: `fzero` only supports the `'TolX'` option. I'm not sure where the `1*e*(-6)` notation came from, but it should be `1e-6` as @Shai points out (i.e., `1*10^-6`).

Comment: I don't recall using `fzero` to ever output the root at each iteration.  The only time we can see this is with verbose outputs with `optimset` and displaying the iterations. In terms of the actual output, I've only known it to output the final root.  The only thing I could possibly suggest is first determine how many iterations it took (25 in your case), then loop over from 1 to 25 and set the maximum number of iterations to be the index number of the loop, run `fzero`, and save that root to the array.  It's very inefficient, but that's all I can come up with for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the question wants you to copy-and-paste the output of the `'Display'` option for [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html). However, that's kind of lame, copy-and-pasting data is a bad habit to get into, and the results only have few decimal places of precision. You can do this using an [output function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/output-functions.html) and the [`'OutputFcn'` option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html#input_argument_options), though it's a bit of a hack.

```
f = @(x)sqrt((x*9.8)/0.25)*tanh(sqrt((0.25*9.8)./x)*4)-36;
global xout fout;
opts = optimset('Display', 'iter', 'TolX', 1e-6, 'OutputFcn', @outfun);
[x0, f0, exitflag] = fzero(f, 100, opts)
xout
fout
```

where `outfun` is a sub-function (or a separate M-file) defined as:

```
function stop = outfun(x, optVals, state)
stop = false;
global xout fout;
switch(state)
    case 'init'
        xout = x;
        fout = optVals.fval;
    case 'iter'
        if ~strcmp(optVals.procedure,'search')
            xout = [xout;x];
            fout = [fout;optVals.fval];
        end
    otherwise

end
```

There are certainly other ways to accomplish this, and probably some that avoid using `global`. Also, note that I didn't output the state during the search phase (root bracketing) of `fzero` as the vectors would be constant.